# CriteriaBuilder in JPA with the method between

Tags: java, jpa

I'm trying to use the CriteriaBuilder.between but I have an error, the code is this:

```
public List<Oferta> findByFechaFinOferta(Date fechaInicio,Date fechaFin){

    CriteriaBuilder cBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Oferta> cQuery =cBuilder.createQuery(Oferta.class);
    Root<Oferta> a = cQuery.from(Oferta.class);

    ParameterExpression <String> param = cBuilder.parameter(String.class);
    cQuery.select(a).where(cBuilder.between(a.get("fechaFin"),fechaInicio,fechaFin));        

    TypedQuery<Oferta> tQuery = em.createQuery(cQuery);
    List<Oferta> oferta = tQuery.getResultList();
    return oferta;
 }
```

The  cQuery.select(a).where(cBuilder.between(a.get("fechaFin"),fechaInicio,fechaFin)); is wrong, but how I can do to make it work out?.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

In this way I can answer myself:

```
 Predicate predicate = cBuilder.between(a.get(Oferta_.fechaFin),fechaInicio,fechaFin);    
    cQuery.select(a).where(predicate);
```